# Rails production dont show background images

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

My images not showed in production (link [here](http://46.101.235.110/)).

My code:

## _header.html.erb

```
<%if action_name == 'index' %>
  <div class="main_header_bg" id="main_head">
  <% end %>
   <header id='header'>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="logo">
      <%= link_to image_tag('logo.png'), root_path%>
  </div>
```

## main.css

```
.main_header_bg {
background-image: url(/header_bg.jpg);
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 718px;
```

## production.log

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/header_bg.jpg"):
```

Images directories:

1. app/assets/images/
2. public/assets/images/

Comment: Which are put in through css?  If so can you post the css code.

Comment: sorry. i edided this is all time :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you precompile your assets? Explicitly in the production environment? This is a very typical issue to run into with people that are pushing Rails projects into production for the first time.

If not, run the following: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Remember that actual files are being written here and you'll need to re-upload your application for the changes to take effect.

Comment: yes, ofc. i had this is error when Capistrano maked a production precompile too, i have this is error, ** DEPLOY FAILED ** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)

```
.main_header_bg {
  background-image: image-url("header_bg.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 718px;
}
```

So change `url` to `image-url` and precompile and restart the site.

Comment: ** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines: